# Convert a function with callback to be sync but not change its calling method signature

Tags: javascript

Not sure if im just being dumb but is there any way other than possibly using some horrific while loop at the end of f() to convert f() into a sync function.
I cant change someFun() i.e make it async function someFun() but i could add await to f() call if needed.
So basically i want f() to return data that is obtained in the callback (imagine http call or something)
I can do whatever i like in f() e.g. Promises etc but someFun can not change to be async function someFun()

```
<script>
  function f(){
    var data;
    var callback = function(){
      data = {name:"bob"};
      console.log("did some stuff");
    }
    setTimeout(callback, 100);
    
    return data;     
  }
  
  function someFunc(){
    console.log('start')
    var data = f();
    console.log('end', data)
  }
  someFunc();
</script>
```

Comment: "using some horrific while loop at the end of f() to convert f() into a sync function" — What wouldn't work. The while loop would run forever and block the main event loop so the callback would never be called.

Comment: "So basically i want f() to return data that is obtained in the callback" — Impossible. That data doesn't exist until the future.

Comment: "can not change to be async function someFun()" — It **is** asynchronous already. The `async` keyword is just syntax to make it easier to manage promises.  Making it return a promise is the standard way to achieve what you want.

Comment: In your toy example, the solution is simple: don't use `setTimeout`.

Comment: If you can't change the `signature` of `someFunc()` but you can change the *contents* of `someFunc()` then you can (1) modify `f()` to return a `Promise` and (2) append `.then()` to the result of `f()` to follow up on that `Promise`.

Comment: Fine. so some crappy  while loop is out. OK.

Comment: The point is i want to wait for the callback to return in the future. Thats what i want it do. When i call f() i want it to wait until the callback is returned and i get the data.

Comment: If i make f() sync somehow - lets say i could do some crappy while loop - how would someFunc be async? I cant use async on f() definition as then i have to use await on the call then i have to define someFunc() as async and i cant change that.

Comment: Thanks  David. Yes but someFunc needs to synchronous. As what is returned from that is used by something. I didnt explain that clearly. My apologies. The issue is someFunc is sync currently and its return value is used by its caller (that i cant alter). someFunc return value is also dependent on the return from f() i.e. its a dependent sync chain currently.

Comment: I think the answer is its not possible as currently written.  And ultimately you would need to change the entire stack to add async and awaits to the functions involved in the call sequence. Or find another way or writing it. I didnt write the code. Im just trying to find a way to localise changes that would need to be made if possible to fix the current issue we have with the callback issue.